# query_posts() in function makes global $wp_query out of sync?

Tags: query-posts, wp-query, globals

This has me stumped for a while already. Either I am missing something very obvious or something very not obvious. I am also not entirely sure if this has something to do with WP or purely PHP mechanics at work.

```
function test() {

    global $wp_query;

    var_dump($wp_query == $GLOBALS['wp_query']);
}

function test2() {

    global $wp_query;

    query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 1));
    var_dump($wp_query == $GLOBALS['wp_query']);
}

test();
test2();
```

Result:

> boolean true
>
> boolean false

Why does `test()` evaluates that to `true`, but `test2()` evaluates that to `false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update with a better example

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8' );
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

function failed_unset()
{   // Copy the variable to the local namespace.
    global $foo;

    // Change the value.
    $foo = 2;

    // Remove the variable.
    unset ( $foo );
}
function successful_unset()
{
    // Remove the global variable
    unset ( $GLOBALS['foo'] );
}

$foo = 1;
print "Original: $foo\n";
failed_unset();
print "After failed_unset(): $foo\n";
successful_unset();
print "After successful_unset(): $foo\n";
```

#### Result

```
Original: 1
After failed_unset(): 2

Notice: Undefined variable: foo in /srv/www/htdocs/global-unset.php on line 21

Call Stack:
    0.0004     318712   1. {main}() /srv/www/htdocs/global-unset.php:0

After successful_unset():
```

`unset()` doesn’t know anything about the global scope in the first function; the variable was just copied to the local namespace.

---

### Old answer

From **wp-includes/query.php**:

```
function &query_posts($query) {
    unset($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] =& new WP_Query();
    return $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query($query);
}
```

Do you see it?

BTW: Someone has made a [nice flowchart](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755) about this very topic. ;)

#### Update

`query_posts()` changes `$GLOBALS` while all references to the variable `$wp_query` that you made available per `global` are *not affected* by [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). That’s one reason to prefer `$GLOBALS` (besides readability).

Comment: Yes, I understand (enough to draw a flowchart) that content of global variable changes. But this doesn't explain why in second function it is different content while accessing essentially same global variable in two different ways?..

Comment: @Rarst I added a note about the behavior of `unset`.

Comment: Still not getting it... The idea is that for same name global variable and member of `$GLOBALS` array point to the same thing... Or do they not? Per docs unsetting `$GLOBALS` unsets global variable, so why it isn't either unset or updated to new value assigned?

Comment: Because the scope of `unset` is not global. It cannot delete a symbol in your function’s scope. This is not very intuitive and a very [common question](http://www.google.com/search?q=unset+global+site%3Abugs.php.net).

Comment: Yes, but `query_posts()` clearly does delete and change the global variable. Then what the heck `$wp_query` in function continues to point to? It cannot (?) be value in local scope, because there never was such value in local scope.

Comment: `global $var` adds a second scope to `$var`, `unset ( $GLOBALS['var] )` deletes `$var` just in one of them, not in both.

Comment: Guess I'll take your word for it... Oh, time that will be wasted tomorrow on getting around this robustly...

Comment: You just replace `global $wp_query;` with `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` and that's it. Come to think of it, I always use $GLOBALS to identify $wp_query and I've never had problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `wp_reset_query();` after your custom query as described at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts ?

Comment: My problem is not **after** custom query, it is **inside** custom query. Essentially `$wp_query`, that was declared global in function, no longer point to correct object after that object was unset and re-set by another function. As per comment discussion with toscho under his answer this seems to be some peculiar behavior of PHP rather than WP.