# Change the "page" slug in pagination

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules, slug

Simple question. When pagination is activated, the URL changes to `"site.com/page/2"`. For my site, this should be `"site.com/paggetto/2"`.

How can I change that rewrite rule? I also want to change `"author"` and other variables.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For some sites in German I use the following plugin to translate `page` to `seite` (the German word for `page`):

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Page to Seite
 * Description: Ersetzt <code>/page/</code> durch <code>/seite/</code>.
 * Author:      Fuxia Scholz
 * License:     MIT
 * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 't5_page_to_seite' ) )
{
    register_activation_hook(   __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
    add_action( 'init', 't5_page_to_seite' );

    function t5_page_to_seite()
    {
        $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->pagination_base = 'seite';
    }

    function t5_flush_rewrite_on_init()
    {
        add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules', 11 );
    }
}
```

Note that you flush the rewrite rules on de/activation **only**. You will need a separate rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` to redirect old URLs to the new ones:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/(.*)/page/(.*) /$1/seite/$2
```

Comment: What's the difference between $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->pagination_base = 'seite' and  $wp_rewrite->search_base        = 'buscar'; ?

Comment: There are subtle and unintuitive [differences](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13765/73) between `global $var;` and `$GLOBALS['var']`. Doesn’t matter in this case, just keep in mind that the latter form is more reliable and easier to read/understand.

Answer (score 23):

Figured out:

```
function re_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    // $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
//  print_r($wp_rewrite);
    $wp_rewrite->author_base        = 'autor';
    $wp_rewrite->search_base        = 'buscar';
    $wp_rewrite->comments_base      = 'comentarios';
    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base    = 'pagina';
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 're_rewrite_rules');
```

At least, that will do the job.

Comment: Just one small notice, because of how extremely costly `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` is in terms of performance, you should never use it on `init`, a much better option is to just visit the Permalink options page, and save the changes a few times, that will flush them for you.

Answer (score 1):

This function will work directly with your translation package, formatting your new base  and prevent to run more than once the flush_rewrite_rules function avoiding bad performance of your blog.

```
function my_change_rewrite_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $bases = array(
        'author_base' => __('Author'), 
        'search_base' => __('Search'), 
        'comments_base' => __('Comments'), 
        'pagination_base' => __('Page')
    );

    foreach ($bases AS $key => $base) {
        $wp_rewrite->{$key} = remove_accents(mb_strtolower($base));
    }

    if ( ! get_option('my_change_rewrite_base_flushed', false) ) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        update_option( 'my_change_rewrite_base_flushed', time());
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_change_rewrite_base');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
function nw_strana() {
    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->pagination_base = 'strana';
}

add_action( 'init', 'nw_strana' );

function nw_rewrite( $rules ) {
    $new_rules = array(
        'obchod/strana/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=product&paged=$matches[1]',
    );

    $rules = array_merge( $new_rules, $rules );

    return $rules;
}

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'nw_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Any idea to remove the "page" from the slug for pagination?
Default mydomain/page/2. I want it to be mydomain/1
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that @Jornes, too much confusion with posts/pages which also don't use a (slug) prefix.

Comment: @Beee Yes. That makes sense. Now, I just leave it as it is.