# Rewriting search permalink

Tags: permalinks, search, htaccess

when typing "a" into my search field (/?s=a) I my `search.php` template is loaded and all results that match that letter are shown.

If I add this to my .htacess …

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.+)$
RewriteRule .* /searchmyblog/%1/? [R,L]
```

and then type "a" into my search the first result of my search is shown. So there is no `search.php` template shown with all the results but rather the page is redirected to "mypage.com/somecategory/amore-mio"

Why is that happening? I simply want to rewrite the normal `/?s=` to `/search/` or any other custom url.

Any ideas on that? I found heaps of posts online, but none of them seem to be state of the art or use some weird JS-hacks that I find unnecessary.

Ideas on that?

Comment: This seems more like an Apache mod_rewrite question rather than WordPress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress doesn’t know that you want the path `/searchmyblog/` as search result base. So when it sees the `a` it tries to find the best match – in your case a post starting with this letter.

To fix that you could modify [my code for the pagination base](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57090/73) to change the search base:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 't5_search_base' ) )
{
    register_activation_hook(   __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
    add_action( 'init', 't5_search_base' );

    function t5_search_base()
    {
        $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->search_base = 'searchmyblog';
    }

    function t5_flush_rewrite_on_init()
    {
        add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules', 11 );
    }
}
```

Now your `.htaccess` should work.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work for me… If I add your lines to my functions.php (and keep my proposed .htaccess lines) and type into my search field I get no results at all. Instead the url in my address-bar changes to ….com/?search-box=test. The weird thing is that `search-box` is the name attribute of my search-inputfield.

Comment: The `name` attribute must be `s` in WordPress.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I changed the `name` attribute to `s` … Now the same happens as previously described. When typing `a` into the search field the first match is shown directly - no search-results. When typing `kdfa` or something weird the addressbar changes to `.com/searchmyblog/kdfa` but results in a 404. So the 404 page is loaded.

Comment: Did you refresh the permalink settings? In your functions.php this cannot happen automatically (and it really doesn’t belong there).

Comment: No idea what I'm doing wrong here, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I have the mentioned lines in my `.htaccess` file and added your lines to my `functions.php`. I refreshed the permalink settings but still the same issue: When typing "a" the first match to that letter is loaded directly. When typing "asdfa" `com/search/asdfa` is in the adressbar but the page-template loaded is not `search.php` but the 404 page.

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution with your help and your posts. I had `flush_rewrite_rules()` in one of my custom-post-templates that might have screwed things up.

Comment: +1 for both answers. Btw: The plugins will have a conflict/crash when used together.