# How can I remove page slug for all pagings?

Tags: pagination

I want to remove page slug for all pagings.

For home page

- Old: www.x.com/page/4
- New: www.x.com/4

For Category page

- Old: www.x.com/category1/page/4
- New: www.x.com/category1/3

How can I achieve it? Or is there any simple plugin for it?

Comment: You may find your answer here. [Change the “page” slug in pagination](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57070/change-the-page-slug-in-pagination)

Comment: Bu this is not "change" question does using this strategy for "removing" creates side effect?

Comment: You could edit the WP database directly (after backing it up) if you can't find a plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code to your `functions.php` and please re-save your permanent link page and **do not forget 301 redirects**

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_page' );

function remove_page(){
    global $wp_rewrite; $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = "";
}
```